# Using two different networks with the same IP ranges

Tags: networking, nat

My camera (Nikon D7500) is hard-coded to use the IP address 192.168.1.1, which is the same as my LAN network range (specifically my router), I would like to find a solution to have it connected without changing my entire LAN or disconnecting from the LAN every time.
I searched for a way to do this with masquerading and creating a sort of alias for the camera's address (and set it to forward it to the camera on the correct interface), but didn't find anything that seems relevant, only answer I saw was saying to change the range of one of the networks?

Edit: I found a temp solution of running a VM that has the USB wireless NIC assigned to it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04, but if I have the idea of what to do, I have the know-how to port it from other versions. Posted here since I thought that netplan might make this easier.

Comment: I'm assuming you have two network interfaces? If so, you can stick the one that connects to the camera in its own network namespace

Comment: Indeed two different network interfaces, but it seems that the driver of the wireless one doesn't support network namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

While not an ideal solution in my opinion, I used network namespaces and it does the job, since I used multiple sourced to find out how to do it, here's what I did is create a small script to be run as root:

```
ip netns add camera
iw phy phy0 set netns name camera
ip netns exec camera ip link set <ifname> up
ip netns exec camera wpa_supplicant -i <ifname> -D nl80211 -c <wpa_config> &
ip netns exec camera dhclient <ifname> 
ip netns exec camera <do the thing>
ip netns exec camera ip link set phy0 netns 1
ip netns pids camera | xargs kill
pids=`ip netns pids camera | wc -l`
if [ $pids -ne 0 ];then
    echo lingering processes, not deleting netns
    exit 1
fi
ip netns del camera
```

What this does:

1. Create a netns called camera
2. Add phy0 card to the camera netns
3. Start the link
4. Connect to a wifi network using a config file (created with wpa_passphrase)
5. Get the address
6. Do what you need (I used gphoto2 to transfer from the camera)
7. Remove the nic from the netns
8. kill leftover processes
9. check for lingering processes
10. If none, delete netns